# What's the post / commenting system used by Stack websites?

Tags: discussion, comments, posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

I love this commenting system! I have no immediate plans on building a website that uses it, but I am curious as to who made it, where to get it from and if they know how awesome it actually is?!?

Comment: While nice, and I agree with the sentiment, this is probably best reserved for meta. (See links at top! Oh, look! An about section and FAQ, too! :)

Comment: It's a part of our codebase, not an external package...